# using matlab gui how to save video

Tags: matlab

How can save and write the video file, which opened
i use this code to open video

```
   [filename, pathname] = uigetfile( ...
   {'*.avi;*.mpg;*.mpeg;.*flv','Video Files (*.avi,*.mpg,*.mpeg,.*flv)';
   '*.*',  'All Files (*.*)'}, ...     
  'Select a video file'); 
mov = mmreader(fullfile(pathname,filename));
implay(filename);
```

**how can save the video after opened it.**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [uiputfile command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uiputfile.html).

```
[filename,pathname]=uiputfile('the same options as your uigetfile');
```

You can then save your video in avi format using the movie2avi command:

```
movie2avi(mov, [pathname filename]);
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were just asking about the GUI part.

Comment: never mind...but i want to save video in matlab folder after openning it.to call it again

Comment: how can i use mmwrite, and mmwrite use to save video?

Comment: Sorry dude, you really need to articulate your problem better.